# Preference Screen option is not showing

Tags: android

My Preference Screen option is not showing, it shows-app. has stopped unexpectedly..

This is my Preference.java-

```
public class Prefs extends PreferenceActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.id.settings);

}
```

}

This is the settings for Preference-

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<CheckBoxPreference 
 android:key="music"
 android:title="@string/music_title"
 android:summary="@string/music_summary" 
 android:defaultValue="true"/>
<CheckBoxPreference 
    android:defaultValue="true"
     android:summary="@string/hints_summary"
     android:title="@string/hints_title"
     android:key="hints"/>
 </PreferenceScreen>
```

This is the Item Select event-

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if(item.getItemId()==R.id.settings)
    {
        startActivity(new Intent(this,Prefs.class));

        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

And the activity is registered well in manifest file.

```
<activity
        android:name=".Prefs"
        android:label="@string/settings_title" >

    </activity>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
addPreferencesFromResource()
```

method should load XML file containing the preferences. 
Therefore, in you code replace

```
addPreferencesFromResource(R.id.settings)
```

with

```
addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.yourPreferenceSettingsFileHere)
```

That will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

please replace **addPreferencesFromResource(R.id.settings);** with  **addPreferencesFromResource(R.layout.settings);**

where settings is the preference xml.

and instead of using **onOptionsItemSelected()**
use
    **onPreferenceTreeClick(PreferenceScreen preferenceScreen, Preference preference) {**

```
 final String key = preference.getKey(); 

 if(key.equal("music"){
     /ur implementaion
     }
 }**
```